# Rewriting C# code using Task.WhenAll in F#

Tags: f#, async-await, task-parallel-library, c#-to-f#

I have the following interface method:

```
Task<string[]> GetBlobsFromContainer(string containerName);
```

and its implementation in C#:

```
var container = await _containerClient.GetContainer(containerName);
var tasks = container.ListBlobs()
                     .Cast<CloudBlockBlob>()
                     .Select(b => b.DownloadTextAsync());
return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

When I try to rewrite it in F#:

```
member this.GetBlobsFromContainer(containerName : string) : Task<string[]> =
    let task = async {
        let! container = containerClient.GetContainer(containerName) |> Async.AwaitTask
        return container.ListBlobs()
               |> Seq.cast<CloudBlockBlob>
               |> Seq.map (fun b -> b.DownloadTextAsync())
               |> ??
    }
    task |> ??
```

I'm stuck with the last lines.

How to return to `Task<string[]>` from F# properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to guess what the type of `containerClient` is and the closest I found is `CloudBlobClient` (which does not have `getContainer: string -> Task<CloubBlobContainer>` but it shouldn't be too hard to adapt). Then, your function might look like as follows:

```
open System
open System.Threading.Tasks
open Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob
open Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage

let containerClient : CloudBlobClient = null

let GetBlobsFromContainer(containerName : string) : Task<string[]> =
    async {
        let container = containerClient.GetContainerReference(containerName)
        return! container.ListBlobs()
               |> Seq.cast<CloudBlockBlob>
               |> Seq.map (fun b -> b.DownloadTextAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask)
               |> Async.Parallel
    } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

I changed the return type to be `Task<string[]>` instead of `Task<string seq>` as I suppose you want to keep the interface. Otherwise, I'd suggest to get rid of the `Task` and use `Async` in F#-only code.

Comment: Sorry, missed to describe `containerClient.GetContainerReference`. It's an abstraction on top of `CloudStorageAccount` from Azure SDK. And yes, you're right, the actual return type is `Task<string[]>`. Used to be `Task<IEnumerable<string>>` but I've changed that.

Comment: The thing I didn't know about is `Async.Parallel` and completely forgot about `return!`.

Answer (score 4):

Will this work?

```
member this.GetBlobsFromContainer(containerName : string) : Task<string seq> =
    let aMap f x = async {
        let! a = x
        return f a }
    let task = async {
        let! container = containerClient.GetContainer(containerName) |> Async.AwaitTask
        return! container.ListBlobs()
            |> Seq.cast<CloudBlockBlob>
            |> Seq.map (fun b -> b.DownloadTextAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask)
            |> Async.Parallel
            |> aMap Array.toSeq
    }
    task |> Async.StartAsTask
```

I had to make some assumptions about `containerClient` etc. so I haven't been able to test this, but at least it compiles.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your response! Sorry, missed to describe what `containerClient.GetContainerReference()` is. Why do you need here an additional function `aMap`?

Comment: In order to convert `Async<string []>` to `Async<string seq>`.

Comment: I see. So if I can return `Task<string[]>` then I don't need it?

Comment: Thank you, sir! Hope you don't mind I've accepted the answer of RCH who has less rep.

Comment: Not at all! He or she also beat me by a couple of seconds :)